# Some Unwanted text appeared on my website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

[image: 1]

some unwanted coontent are coming up on my wordpress site . how i fix it

How we remove this unwanted text

Comment: seems html tag not closed properly. checkout your code

Comment: can you send a SS of this in dev tools from chrome then we can see the hierarchy of the page, it looks to be an issue with a header element in Elementor though but please send that SS.